# On configuration of serial ports on wine

Tags: wine, serial-port

I have wine 1.6 on Ubuntu 12.04 and I have tried to get PINReader.exe on http://www.eobd2.com/upload/pro/renault-pin-reader-v312.rar to detect serial ports (COM1) automatically. I have created symbolic link com1 to /dev/ttyS0 in ~/.wine/dosdevices and written MODE="0666" to 50-udev-default.rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/. It changes the mode on next boot. The program opens an error window with the text "Error: COM PORTS not Found!".

I have added user defined serial port to wine registry using wine regedit according to http://www.downtowndougbrown.com/2013/03/getting-x-ctu-in-wine-to-detect-your-serial-ports/. I get an error message

```
wine: Call from 0x7b83bbd5 to unimplemented function cfgmgr32.dll.CM_Open_DevNode_Key
```

on terminal. The actual program opened an error window with the text "External exception 0x80000100.". The next step was to override cfgmgr32.dll by the native one. However, the program again opens an error window with the text "Error: COM PORTS not Found!". What to do next?

Comment: Did you run the program with all the debugging options activated? What's the exact output on the console? Did you noticed that the blogpost you linked has extremally more debugging and steps you are reporting, from understanding how the programs works to what wine does when looking for serial ports?

Comment: No, because there was a huge amount of messages. Without debugging options enabled there was a couple of font error messages with fixme: -prefix. Yes, I noticed and I got X-CTU to find COM1, but I didn't have enough drive to find out the usual ways to use port enumeration in C programming on Windows and guess what else is possibly missing from the wine registry.

Comment: Could you upload all the messages for everyone to see? Also, did you try another distro?